# Relative path in a php site on a windows server

Tags: php, iis

I have a PHP enabled windows server, where i have to get a site working.

Its all well and good, the php is working, afaik. But for some reason i can not get relative paths to work in the page header.

I have this folder structure(only relevant folders):

wwwroot/Sitename/

wwwroot/Sitename/Control

wwwroot/Sitename/Images

wwwroot/Sitename/Model

wwwroot/Sitename/View

In IIS i have set the  the physical path to wwwroot/Sitename/Control. This loads pages.php(which is located here) which in turn loads wwwroot/Sitename/view/header.php and footer.php.

This works perfectly, however in header.php there are some references to some javascript (and other) files located in wwwroot/Sitename/Model   eg.:wwwroot/Sitename/model/js.js

(eg:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../model/main.css" />
```

)

This file is not found by the browser when loaded. I am sure it has something to do with the fact that i have set the physical path as i have but this is needed to load pages.php.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? either why the relative path is not working or perhaps another way to set the physical path/something similar.

EDIT: clarifications in parenthesis

Comment: What is: (a) the url typed in in the browser, (b) the url that would refer to the javascript files and (c) the (relative) url you find in the page source?

Comment: A:www.sitename.com
B:Not sure what you mean here?
C:../model/js.js

Answer (score 0):

use ../ to go down a folder.

Try this in your header.php:

../Model

Comment: This is actually what i have already. And for some reason it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use Absolute urls?

```
$SiteURL = 'http://www.your_iis_sever.com';
```

Then in your javascript files use

```
<?php echo $SiteURL;?>/path/to/js/jscript.js
```

infront of the links. Make sure its all correct => Check the source code when viewing the page if the paths are correct. From there its easier to navigate.